# Adding char from char array to char arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to add a char to an ArrayList of Chars from an array of chars for reasons I won't talk about for fear of making the post long. I am using this basic code:

```
for(char ch: c){
    this.age.add(ch);
}
```

Where c is the array, and age is the ArrayList. Keep in mind that age is not initialized, therefore it is null. My question is, why am I getting a null pointer exception when I compile and run this?

Comment: `this.age` is null  ? Do you have elements in `c` ?

Comment: The answer is in the question. age is not initialized, therefore it's null, therefore trying to call a method on it will throw a NullPointerException. Corollary: to avoid the exception, age needs to be initialized before calling any method on it.

Comment: yes. It is never initialized, therefore null.

Comment: So what would you initialize it to JB? first element zero?

Comment: You don't need to initialize any element inside the list. You just need to create the list, which is empty by default: `age = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might be you are not initialized `age`. initialize it like,

```
List<Character>  age = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

Exception coming because you just left it like

```
 List<Character>  age;
```

So by default reference is  null. and calling a method on it's like

```
null.method()  //NullPointerException
```

Comment: ah I see. It's not initialized w/o the ending. Thanks!

Comment: @comscis Happens. Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a nullpointer because age, the Arraylist is null. You need to initialize it before you add elements.

```
List<Character>  age = new ArrayList<Character>();
for(char ch: c){
    this.age.add(ch);
}
```

Initialize age before the for loop, if you do it in the for loop you will reinitialize it each time and lose your data.